# Sendmail configure masquerade domain

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, email-server

i'm really new to sendmail and i'm trying to configure it properly as my server mta.
First of all i'm trying to accomplish some easy tasks as for example masquerade the domain name to show the one i need. I mean, i would like the `from` field of the email to show `foo@myDomain.com`
In order to do that i first try with the following, but didn't worked:

```
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `myDomain.com')dnl
FEATURE(`relay_entire_domain')dnl
```

Should this worked?

As it didn't worked for me, then i tried:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(myDomain.com)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(myDomain.com)dnl
```

Last block worked fine, but i still think the first one should have worked.

Could someone point what's the error on the first block?
Should have it worked?
Is the syntax obsolete?
Lastly, could someone tell what's the difference between the first and the last block? Thanks in advanced :)

PD: Byusing `confMAILER_NAME` satement should i be able to set a default user name, i.e. `myUser@....`

Comment: can you clarify what you mean with a "default username" ?

Answer (score 1):

The second block is what you use to masquerade the "from" domain. The first block controls the HELO response of the server. Say the server's actual hostname is `host1.abc.net`. Configuring `define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `abc.net')dnl` will present the sending server's name as `abc.net`.

Answer (score 0):

The first block is saying that you should relay the hosts in your domain, as you can check in the [sendmail documentation.](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/features.html)

The second block, instead, talks about masquerading; you're asking to masquerade both the domain in your message headers and those in the envelope.